# How to Lay a grid of 8 elements per row using Lightning Layout on a dynamic list?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I wanted to lay a grid using lightning layout for 8 elements per row on a list populated dynamically.

What I want to accomplish is given below

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1001</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1002</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1003</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1004</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
         <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
             <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1005</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1006</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1007</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">A-1008</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

The above lays 8 elements for a static DOM. I want the same to be accomplished for laying a list dynamically.

Thanks for the help in advance.
**************UPDATE***************
After implementing sfdcfox solution I am getting the below layout. Any idea why to fix the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more complicated layouts, such as in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/220290), the answer is to reform your data as a list of lists, which would make your code look more like this:

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.masterList}" var="row">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="around-small">
        <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
          <aura:iteration items="{!row}" var="cell">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="3" padding="around-small">
                <div class="custom-box">{!cell}</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
          </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
  </aura:iteration>
</lightning:layout>
```

Your data would be organized as follows:

```
[['A-1001','A-1002','A-1003','A-1004'],['A-1005','A-1006','A-1007','A-1008']]
```

---

Full Demo:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="masterList" type="List" default="[['A-1001','A-1002','A-1003','A-1004'],['A-1005','A-1006','A-1007','A-1008']]" />

    <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" multipleRows="true">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.masterList}" var="row">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="6">
                <lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!row}" var="cell">
                        <lightning:layoutItem size="3" class="slds-border_top slds-border_left slds-border_right slds-border_bottom slds-p-around_medium slds-align_absolute-center">
                            <div class="custom-box">{!cell}</div>
                        </lightning:layoutItem>
                    </aura:iteration>
                </lightning:layout>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:iteration>
    </lightning:layout>
</aura:application>
```

Comment: iHi @sfdcfox I tried implementing your solution. But getting the grid as I have posted the image in the question. Any solutions?

Comment: @AbhiramSheshadri I didn't test this one, but I suspect it's the padding. Could you try removing it?

Comment: I tried removing the padding, still I am having the same grid.

Comment: @AbhiramSheshadri The problem is your extra, mystery CSS. It works correctly in core SLDS with no additional styles, so something you've done in your style sheet is the cause.

Comment: Actually my CSS is empty. There is no extra CSS in the component. Don't know what's causing the issue. Anyway thanks for the comments. Yet to find a solution for the issue.

Comment: @AbhiramSheshadri I've been playing around with this, I made some of the modifications and cleaned it up. Feel free to copy it to a new app and play around with it.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot :) It's working!!! The issue was with the inner LayoutItem styling I believe.

Answer (score -1):

It will look like below. more example can be found [here](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/)

```
<aura:component>
  <aura:iteration items="{!v.list}" var="item">
    <div class="slds-grid">
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.one</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.two</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.three</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.four</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.five</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.six</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.seven</span>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-col">
        <span>item.eight</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```